# iTextSharp - How to input image (PNG) from project resource?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, resources, embedded-resource

I have iTextSharp creating a pdf for me in VB.net. Everything was working famously, except now I want to embed an image. I tried this:

```
Dim test = My.Resources.MyImage
Dim logo = Image.GetInstance(test)
```

This an error though:

> 'GetInstance' cannot be called with these arguments

It appears as though it expects a path, and is getting a System.Drawing.Bitmap type.

Is there any way that I can add a project resource image to my PDF? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the overloads for `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance()` takes an `System.Drawing.Image`, so convert your PNG resource into this type and then use this overload.  Something like this:

```
Dim test As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(My.Resources.MyImage.GetHbitmap())
Dim logo As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(test, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```